# Javascript: Class constructor basics - define property in separate method

Tags: javascript, function, class

The original question was set on hold, so here is a new try in a different wording. I hope, it's getting clearer now:

**Question:** How can I do the following with private methods instead of using prototype?

```
function numberPlusFive(nr) {
    this.number = number + 5;
    this.square = this.calculateSquare();
    this.isPrime = this.checkIfPrime();
}
numberPlusFive.prototype = {
    calculateSquare: function() {
        return this.number * this.number;
    },
    checkIfPrime: function() {
        // check if this.number is a prime number
        return true; // or false
    },
}
```

The methods (calculateSquare, checkIfPrime) are not needed anymore once the class is constructed. I want to make the calculations in separate methods, but I don't need the methods to be public.

**Important:** I need the already calculated properties for further calculations (so in this example, `this.number` **must** be available in `calculateSquare` and `checkIfPrime` - and no, I can't just recalculate `this.number` because in the real script, it takes a long time to be calculated.).

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Question: do you need `calculateSquare & checkIfPrime` as a public methods?

Comment: No, I don't need calculateSquare & checkIfPrime as public methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can declare calculateSquare and checkIfPrime function within the constructor and return another object.

```
function myFirstJsClass(number) {

    var calculateSquare = function(n) {
        return n * n;
    };

    var checkIfPrime = function(n) {
        //check if prime
        return true; // or false
    };

    this.number = number;
    this.square = calculateSquare(number);
    this.isPrime = checkIfPrime(this.square);

}
```

alternatively, you can also declare them outside and call them in the constructor.

```
var calculateSquare = function(n) {
    return n * n;
};

var checkIfPrime = function(n) {
    //check if prime
    return true; // or false
};

function myFirstJsClass(number) {
    this.number = number;
    this.square = calculateSquare(number);
    this.isPrime = checkIfPrime(this.square);
}
```

if you don't want to pass everything as parameter you can also call the function using call() http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp

```
var calculateSquare = function() {
    this.square= this.number * this.number;
};

var checkIfPrime = function() {
    //check if prime with this.square
    this.isPrime = true; // or false
};

function myFirstJsClass(number) {
    this.number = number;
    calculateSquare.call(this);
    checkIfPrime.call(this);
}
```

Comment: Your examples are not really "classes" in any form, just object generators.

Comment: I've modified my snippets. I think the main hint still stands: he can define function both as variables in the constructor or externally, and not relying on the "this" property inside the two functions.

Comment: Looks good to me :-) Thanks for the update

Comment: Ok, that's more or less how I did it in the beginning. What if I have ten "this."-variables that I need to use in the method. Is it the only way to pass all ten variables? Or is there any way to access the "this."-variables directly from within the methods in your first code snippet?

Comment: I've edited the answer: you can invoke the functions with "call": allows you to call the function setting the "this" property manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use an IIFE

```
var MyClass = (function() {
   let calcSquare = number => number * number;
   let isPrime = number => { /* your prime code */ };
   class MyClass {
      constructor(number) {
          this.square = calcSquare(number);
          this.isPrime = isPrime(number);
      }
   }

   return MyClass;
})();
```

That way those functions are just private function, and can be used however you want.

(*technically* you do not need the iife in es6, but I just assumed that all of your code was in one file, if it isnt then all you would need to do is just export `MyClass` and the other function will be private.)

---

or without es6:

```
var MyClass = (function() {
   var calcSquare = function(number) { return number * number; };
   var isPrime = function(number) { /* your prime code */ };

   function MyClass(number) {
      this.square = calcSquare(number);
      this.isPrime = isPrime(number);
   }

   return MyClass;
})();
```

Comment: If you're using ES6 and `class` already, why would you wrap that in an IIFE rather than just exporting the class but not the functions?

Comment: ssube True :-) But the OP never stated he was using any modules so I just assumes otherwise, but yes, if it is an external file, the iife is not necessary :-)

Comment: All the code is in one file, that's no problem. Can you add an example how to use these classes? I can't see how to pass the number. And: I just edited my questions - I need to use the result of calcSquare in my prime code. Is this possible in any of the two suggestions?

Comment: So just pass `this.square` into your prime function. or just recalc square in your prime function if you want @am2124429  I showed in my example where the number is being passed.

Comment: Ok, I just found out that I can pass the number as before ... but I don't understand why this works. But using this.square in my prime code in the second code snippet doesn't work. It returns `undefined`

Comment: That is because you cannot use `this` inside those functions, they do not know what `this` is.  You have to pass the parameters you want to use to those functions.